# Unable to import sample custom geocode file

Tags: tableau-api

Here is a sample custom geocode file you can download from Tableau's web site:

```
Country (Name),State/Province,City,Latitude,Longitude
United States,Florida,Starke,29.94413,-82.109827
United States,Florida,Micanopy,29.504692,-82.279823
United States,Florida,Waldo,29.789688,-82.167325
United States,Florida,Williston,29.38747,-82.446771
United States,Florida,Lebanonn Station,28.032806,-82.000278
```

But it won't import into my Tableau 10.4 desktop, at least not in the nice way it does in their video. It doesn't recognize any of the locations. Any ideas why?

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of Desktop with the data imported, showing the left hand data pane and what you have in Rows, Columns, and on the marks card? Mapping is pretty straight forward out-of-the-box functionality and your data looks clean so perhaps the dimensions don't have their geographic role set properly. A screenshot that includes the little data type icons next to dimension and measure names will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is a bug in version 10.4. They are working on a fix.